# Deletes in one-to-one relationships? Normal behavior?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, relationship

When working in Access, whenever I delete a record from one table - it's corresponding record in another table is also deleted when defined as a one-to-one relationship.  This would be normal behavior when I tell it to enforce referential integrity with concerns to deletes and updates (how I understand it).  However, it seems to also do it when I leave the enforce referential integrity option for deletes cleared, or when I leave the entire section on referential integrity cleared as well.

Basically, I have one table which is a list of suppliers that is a source for another database application that wasn't written by myself.  I am using this supplier table in my application, augmenting the information stored in the first program with information entered by the user in the second program in a separate table - but linked using a one-to-one relationship (relationship using primary keys in both tables).

I don't want a delete of the secondary information record to result in the deletion of the data in the primary table - which would cause major issues (to put it mildly) in the first program.  Is there a way to do this?

--Edited to add on 5/27/2009 @ 1600--

Here is the SQL script to create the Supplier_Master table from the first application:

```
USE [gtdata_test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Supplier_Master]    Script Date: 05/27/2009 15:58:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master](
    [Supplier_Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Supplier_Master_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Salutation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Contact] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EMail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Zip] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Last_Review] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Rating] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Received] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Reject] [datetime] NULL,
    [Enabled] [int] NULL,
    [User1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [User2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SupType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Supplier_Master$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Supplier_Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Address$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Address])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Address$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$City$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([City])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$City$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Contact$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Contact])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Contact$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Country$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Country])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Country$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$EMail$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([EMail])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$EMail$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Fax$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Fax])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Fax$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Phone$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Phone])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Phone$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Salutation$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Salutation])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Salutation$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$State$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([State])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$State$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Supplier_Code$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Supplier_Code])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Supplier_Code$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Supplier_Master_Name$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Supplier_Master_Name])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Supplier_Master_Name$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$SupType$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([SupType])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$SupType$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$User1$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([User1])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$User1$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$User2$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([User2])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$User2$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Zip$disallow_zero_length] CHECK  ((len([Zip])>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SSMA_CC$Supplier_Master$Zip$disallow_zero_length]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplier_Master] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Enabled]
GO
```

Here is the SQL script to create the tblSupplierInfo table from the second application:

```
USE [instkeeper_test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo]    Script Date: 05/27/2009 15:57:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo](
    [strSupplierID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [bolSupAltShipAddyRep] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupAltShipAddyCal] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupInsistNet30] [bit] NULL,
    [bolRMARequireRepair] [bit] NULL,
    [bolRMARequireCalibration] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupShipOrCourier] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupRequireMSDS] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupBlanketPO] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupRequirePricing] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupBlankPricing] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupFaxPOSend] [bit] NULL,
    [bolAdditionalPaperworkRepair] [bit] NULL,
    [bolAdditionalPaperworkCalibration] [bit] NULL,
    [strRMARepairWordage] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [strRMACalibrationWordage] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [intBlanketPO] [int] NULL,
    [bolUseFedExNumber] [bit] NULL,
    [strFedExNumber] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [bolUseUPSNumber] [bit] NULL,
    [strUPSNumber] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [bolSupA2LAAccredited] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupFreightAllow] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupFreightOnly] [bit] NULL,
    [bolSupUseMiscNum] [bit] NULL,
    [strSupMiscFreightNum] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [tblSupplierInfo$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [strSupplierID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Supplier Name' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'strSupplierID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Alternate Shipping Address - Repairs?' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'bolSupAltShipAddyRep'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Alternate Shipping Address - Calibrations?' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'bolSupAltShipAddyCal'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Force Net 30 Wordage?' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'bolSupInsistNet30'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Do repairs require RMAs?' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'bolRMARequireRepair'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Do calibrations require RMAs?' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'bolRMARequireCalibration'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Use Courier?' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'bolSupShipOrCourier'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Requires MSDS(s)?' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tblSupplierInfo', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'bolSupRequireMSDS'
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupAltShipAddyRep]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupAltShipAddyCal]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupInsistNet30]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolRMARequireRepair]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolRMARequireCalibration]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupShipOrCourier]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupRequireMSDS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupBlanketPO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [bolSupRequirePricing]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupBlankPricing]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolSupFaxPOSend]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolAdditionalPaperworkRepair]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolAdditionalPaperworkCalibration]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ('RMA #') FOR [strRMARepairWordage]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ('RMA #') FOR [strRMACalibrationWordage]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [intBlanketPO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolUseFedExNumber]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblSupplierInfo] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bolUseUPSNumber]
GO
```

Comment: Tell us exactly how you are doing the deletes. Executing SQL?, From a form? From a table/query, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's normal behaviour. If your form is based on a query that contains a single one-to-one relationship and you delete a "record" it will delete records in both tables.

You need to suppress the normal delete process and run the delete manually via a custom button.

```
Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)

  'this cancels all normal deletes'
  Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Then create a Delete button

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()

  Dim oDB as DAO.Database

  oDB.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblSupplierInfo WHERE strSupplierID = '" & Me.strSupplierID & "'", dbFailOnError

  Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of coding the first routine you could also change the forms Allow Deletions property to no.

Answer (score 0):

How is SQL Server involved?  If you don't have cascading deletes on in either Access or SQL Server, perhaps there is a trigger?

Comment: SQL Server is storing the databases involved, Microsoft Access is being used to access the tables on the server, sorry about not putting this in the question earlier.

I have no triggers defined on the database server, so I'd assume I have the relationship defined strangely.  I had it set to be the read only table on the right hand side of the relationship definition, and not the left.  Would that be what's causing this behavior?

Comment: Please post the complete table creation scripts from SQL Server, including the constraints.